# Varnish - How can I set TTL in response header?

Tags: varnish, ttl

I have not tried this before on Varnish. And I must admit that my last experience with Varnish was way back - version 2.1.5 days!

I have set varnish 6.x as a simple/basic static http-cache.
I have achieved most of what I wish to from this varnish, and then I had an idea to display cache-ttl info as response header. Here, I hit a roadblock. I am surely doing it incorrectly. Possibly vcl_delivery may not get beresp.ttl. I am not sure. This is what I added to vcl_deliver

```
 set resp.http.X-TTL = "TTL (" + beresp.ttl +")";
```

I get compile error:

```
Mar 19 07:05:41  varnishd[55516]: Message from VCC-compiler:
Mar 19 07:05:41  varnishd[55516]: ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 97 Pos 40) -- (Pos 49)
Mar 19 07:05:41  varnishd[55516]:     set resp.http.X-TTL = "TTL (" + beresp.ttl +")";
Mar 19 07:05:41  varnishd[55516]: ---------------------------------------##########------
Mar 19 07:05:41  varnishd[55516]: Not available in method 'vcl_deliver'.
```

I tried assigning beresp.ttl as header variable in vcl_backend_response:

```
set beresp.http.x-ttl = beresp.ttl
```

That did not work either.

Makes me wonder, if this is possible? If so, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Varnish 4, backend & client logic have been split up in separate threads. This split is also reflected in VCL.

At the client side of Varnish you have objects like `req` and `resp` to access request and response information. When you have to access the backend, the `req` object gets used to build the `bereq` object and the response is stored in the `beresp` object.

As you have noticed the `beresp` context is not available in `vcl_deliver`, because the delivery stage happens at the client side.

That's why it's better to set the `X-TTL` header at the backend side.

Here's the VCL code to do it:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.X-TTL = "TTL (" + beresp.ttl +")";
}
```

Comment: I tried that in a more direct way, as mentioned in the Question. So, what I gather from your reply is that we cannot use 'beresp' in vcl_deliver. In other words, there is no way to expose a set TTL for a URL in its response header?

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood it. I do not need to set it on vcl_deliver. I guess I missed seeing it in response when I set it up before. Thanks for pointing that out.